# How to express a NOT IN query with ActiveRecord/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm hoping there is a easy solution that doesn't involve `find_by_sql`, if not then I guess that will have to work.

I found [this article](http://trevorturk.com/2007/03/19/active-record-and-the-in-clause/) which references this:

```
Topic.find(:all, :conditions => { :forum_id => @forums.map(&:id) })
```

which is the same as

```
SELECT * FROM topics WHERE forum_id IN (<@forum ids>)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do `NOT IN` with that, like:

```
SELECT * FROM topics WHERE forum_id NOT IN (<@forum ids>)
```

Comment: As an FYI, Datamapper has had specific support for NOT IN. Example: `Person.all(:name.not => ['bob','rick','steve'])`

Comment: sorry for being ignorant, but what is Datamapper?  is that part of rails 3?

Comment: data mapper is an alternative way of storing data, it replaces Active Record with a different structure and then you write your model related stuff such as queries, differently.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Rails 4+:

```
Article.where.not(title: ['Rails 3', 'Rails 5'])
```

Rails 3:

```
Topic.where('id NOT IN (?)', Array.wrap(actions))
```

Where `actions` is an array with: `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: This is the proper approach with the latest Active Record query model

Comment: @NewAlexandria is right, so you'd have to do something like `Topic.where('id NOT IN (?)', (actions.empty? ? '', actions)`. It would still break on nil, but I find that the array you pass in is usually generated by a filter that will return `[]` at the very least and never nil. I recommend checking out Squeel, a DSL on top of Active Record. Then you could do: `Topic.where{id.not_in actions}`, nil/empty/or otherwise.

Comment: @danneu just swap `.empty?` for `.blank?` and you are nil-proof

Comment: (actions.empty? ? '', actions) by @daaneu should be (actions.empty? ? '' : actions)

Comment: I think the function returning the actions array should take care that it is [] instead of nil

Comment: go for the rails 4 notation: Article.where.not(title: ['Rails 3', 'Rails 5'])

Comment: Like @NewAlexandria said, **this does not work when the variable is `[]` or `nil`**. You end up with `id NOT in (null)`. To get around that use `presence`, like so: `Topic.where( 'id NOT IN (?)', actions.presence || "" )`

Comment: @JoshuaPinter just use `Array.wrap(actions)`

Answer (score 158):

FYI, In Rails 4, you can use `not` syntax:

```
Article.where.not(title: ['Rails 3', 'Rails 5'])
```

Comment: finally! what took them so long to include that? :)

Answer (score 54):

since rails 4:

```
Topic.where.not(forum_id: @forum_ids)
```

Please notice that eventually you do not want the forum_ids to be the ids list, but rather a subquery, if so then you should do something like this before getting the topics:

```
@forum_ids = Forum.where(/*whatever conditions are desirable*/).select(:id)
```

in this way you get everything in a single query: something like:

```
select * from topic 
where forum_id in (select id 
                   from forum 
                   where /*whatever conditions are desirable*/)
```

**Also notice that eventually you do not want to do this, but rather a join - what might be more efficient.**

Comment: A join _might_ be more efficient, but not necessarily. Make sure to use `EXPLAIN`!

Answer (score 49):

You can try something like:

```
Topic.find(:all, :conditions => ['forum_id not in (?)', @forums.map(&:id)])
```

You might need to do `@forums.map(&:id).join(',')`.  I can't remember if Rails will the argument into a CSV list if it is enumerable.

You could also do this:

```
# in topic.rb
named_scope :not_in_forums, lambda { |forums| { :conditions => ['forum_id not in (?)', forums.select(&:id).join(',')] }

# in your controller 
Topic.not_in_forums(@forums)
```

Answer (score 25):

To expand on @Trung Lê answer, in Rails 4 you can do the following:

```
Topic.where.not(forum_id:@forums.map(&:id))
```

And you could take it a step further.
If you need to first filter for only published Topics and **then** filter out the ids you don't want, you could do this:

```
Topic.where(published:true).where.not(forum_id:@forums.map(&:id))
```

Rails 4 makes it so much easier!

Answer (score 12):

The accepted solution fails if `@forums` is empty. To workaround this I had to do

```
Topic.find(:all, :conditions => ['forum_id not in (?)', (@forums.empty? ? '' : @forums.map(&:id))])
```

Or, if using Rails 3+:

```
Topic.where( 'forum_id not in (?)', (@forums.empty? ? '' : @forums.map(&:id)) ).all
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers above should suffice you but if you are doing a lot more of such predicate and complex combinations check out [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel). You will be able to doing something like:

```
Topic.where{{forum_id.not_in => @forums.map(&:id)}}
Topic.where{forum_id.not_in @forums.map(&:id)} 
Topic.where{forum_id << @forums.map(&:id)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can these forum ids be worked out in a pragmatic way? e.g. can you find these forums somehow - if that is the case you should do something like

```
Topic.all(:joins => "left join forums on (forums.id = topics.forum_id and some_condition)", :conditions => "forums.id is null")
```

Which would be more efficient than doing an SQL `not in`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the [meta_where plugin](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) by Ernie Miller. Your SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM topics WHERE forum_id NOT IN (<@forum ids>)
```

...could be expressed like this:

```
Topic.where(:forum_id.nin => @forum_ids)
```

Ryan Bates of Railscasts created a [nice screencast explaining MetaWhere](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch).

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but to my eyes it certainly looks better than an embedded SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

This way optimizes for readability, but it's not as efficient in terms of database queries:

```
# Retrieve all topics, then use array subtraction to
# find the ones not in our list
Topic.all - @forums.map(&:id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The original post specifically mentions using numeric IDs, but I came here looking for the syntax for doing a NOT IN with an array of strings.

ActiveRecord will handle that nicely for you too:

```
Thing.where(['state NOT IN (?)', %w{state1 state2}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql in your conditions:

```
Topic.find(:all, :conditions => [ "forum_id NOT IN (?)", @forums.map(&:id)])
```

Answer (score -1):

Piggybacking off of jonnii:

```
Topic.find(:all, :conditions => ['forum_id not in (?)', @forums.pluck(:id)])
```

using pluck rather than mapping over the elements

found via [railsconf 2012 10 things you did not know rails could do](http://confreaks.com/videos/889-railsconf2012-ten-things-you-didn-t-know-rails-could-do)

Answer (score -1):

When you query a blank array add "<< 0" to the array in the where block so it doesn't return "NULL" and break the query.

```
Topic.where('id not in (?)',actions << 0)
```

If actions could be an empty or blank array.

Comment: Warning: this actually adds a 0 to the array, so it's no longer empty. It also has the side-effect of modifying the array -- double danger if you use it later. Much better to wrap it in an if-else and use Topic.none/all for the edge cases

Comment: A safer way is: `Topic.where("id NOT IN (?)", actions.presence || [0])`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a more complex "not in" query, using a subquery in rails 4 using squeel. Of course very slow compared to the equivalent sql, but hey, it works.

```
    scope :translations_not_in_english, ->(calmapp_version_id, language_iso_code){
      join_to_cavs_tls_arr(calmapp_version_id).
      joins_to_tl_arr.
      where{ tl1.iso_code == 'en' }.
      where{ cavtl1.calmapp_version_id == my{calmapp_version_id}}.
      where{ dot_key_code << (Translation.
        join_to_cavs_tls_arr(calmapp_version_id).
        joins_to_tl_arr.    
        where{ tl1.iso_code == my{language_iso_code} }.
        select{ "dot_key_code" }.all)}
    }
```

The first 2 methods in the scope are other scopes which declare the aliases cavtl1 and tl1. << is the not in operator in squeel.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

If someone want to use two or more conditions, you can do that:

```
your_array = [1,2,3,4]
your_string = "SOMETHING"

YourModel.where('variable1 NOT IN (?) AND variable2=(?)',Array.wrap(your_array),your_string)
```