# Rails get all items from all orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`@orders.closed_today` is an array of all orders closed for today.

How can I list get all the items for this?

i.e. `@items = @orders.closed_today.items`

---

Update
Reports html

```
<% @items = Item.in_orders(@orders.closed_today) %>
```

Items model

```
scope :in_orders, lambda { |orders| where('order_id is in (?)', orders.map(&:id).join(',') ) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: map the items.

```
@items = @orders.closed_today.all(:include => :items).map(&:items)
```

That will give you:

```
=> [[item1,item2],[item2,item3]]
```

To get unique items:

```
@orders.closed_today.all(:include => :items).map(&:items).flatten.uniq
```

This is not a sustainable way of fetching related objects; beware N+1 performance problems.

More generally, you should probably do something like this:

```
class Item
  scope :closed_today, joins(:orders) & Order.closed_today
end
```

and just call:

```
Item.closed_today
```

Comment: This sort of worked.  Need the results flattened to a single [].  Something in the line of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/not-in-rails where I can search if an Item.order_id is in the @orders.closed_today.  When tried answer in link got a SQLite3::SQLException: near "in": syntax error:  Updated question to show what I tried.

Comment: Added scope on Item using scope on Order; this is more what you were looking for, correct?

Comment: Turned your scope to lambda to be flexible with scoped date ranges.  Thanks!