# How to implement "NOT IN" SQL-select in activeRecord

Tags: android

Have some question:

In my app I use (ActiveRecord)org.kroz.activerecord

And need a SQL-select that contains "NOT IN" condition,
but I do not know how to implement:
Something this

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id NOT IN (5, 6, 8)"
```

Here is JavaDoc for method find()

```
find(type, distinct, whereClause, whereArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit)
Return all instances of an entity that match the given criteria.
Parameters:
<T> Any ActiveRecordBase class.
type The class of the entities to return.
distinct
whereClause The condition to match (Don't include "where").
whereArgs The arguments to replace "?" with.
groupBy
having
orderBy
limit
Returns:
A generic list of all matching entities.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4307411/850326

Comment: there in Ruby-style. I need same in java..
Maybe something like this: find(MyClass.class, false, "id NOT IN ?", new String[] {5, 6, 8},..... But here argument is array.. Would it work?