# Complex Rails BETWEEN SQL Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to create a search query that finds all users with specified hourly rates.  The users have hourly rate ranges such as $55/h to $75/h.  A site visitor will search for these users with another range such as $40/h to $60, which should display all overlapping registered users.

The old working plain string query was:

```
(users.hour_price_low BETWEEN :low_price AND :high_price OR hour_price_high BETWEEN :low_price AND :high_price).
```

I need to refactor this to searchable in an **array query**.  My starting point for the refactor was this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form).

I have modified the methods to accomodate OR clauses, no problems there.

```
##This is where I am getting hung up.  I can't get the syntax correct.##

def low_price_or_conditions
    ["users.hour_price_low BETWEEN ?", price_low..price_high] unless price.blank?
end

def high_price_or_conditions
    ["users.hour_price_high BETWEEN ?", price_low..price_high] unless price.blank?
end
```

Finally:

```
@users = User.where(conditions)
```

Which outputs this error:

```
Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80 OR users.hour_pr' at line 1: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (users.hour_price_low BETWEEN 60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80 OR users.hour_price_high BETWEEN 60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80)
```

I am open to any suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the range, and just use the between clause as you were previously.

ie

```
["users.hour_price_low BETWEEN ? AND ?", price_low, price_high]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look up two different values (hour_price_high and hour_price_low) being inside ranges, so you could try to use the IN predicate in SQL.

```
def low_price_or_conditions
    ["users.hour_price_low IN (?)", price_low..price_high] unless price.blank?
end

def high_price_or_conditions
    ["users.hour_price_high IN (?)", price_low..price_high] unless price.blank?
end
```

Although I am not too sure if the conditional "unless" is exactly what you want. From the RailsCast I understood that this was meant to skip adding this filter to your search/find filters in case the user doesn't chose to search by that attribute.

Comment: While you are at it just watch out for NOT IN. This troubled me quite a bit there was [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/not-in-rails/7415256#7415256) too. There are lots of way suggested there too.