# Rails Import CSV records Delete all and Recreate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, import

I tried implementing a CSV import function based on:
[Rails Cast Import CSV](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel)

It works great for updating and inserting of new records by finding records based on their ids and edit or create them.

However, it does not take into account of records that are removed from the CSV file.

I am inexperienced and what I thought of that could possibly solve this problem is to delete all the records and rebuilt them. But obviously, there would be performance issues with that.

So, I would like to ask for advice on how you guys would tackle such an issue.

Comment: before the import you can save all ids of existing records into an array and while processing the csv line by line, for each record processed the corresponding id is removed from this array. afterwards you can process the ids left in the array because these a records not contained in your csv

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need an exclusion query.

You can collect the row_ids in to an Array and then delete all the records

```
ids = []
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
 ids << row["id"]
end

Topic.where('id not in (?)',ids).delete_all
```

FYI: [How to express a NOT IN query with ActiveRecord/Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/how-to-express-a-not-in-query-with-activerecord-rails)

After this you can run your normal csv import.

Answer (score 1):

@Jethroo's suggestion is perfectly good. You could also just add the IDs of the items you're adding to an array as you process them, then run through you're existing records and delete if not in the processed array. F.E.:

```
processed_ids = []
@csv_row.each do |r|
  process r
  processed_ids << r[:id]
end

Object.all.each do |o|
  next if processed_ids.include? o.id
  o.destroy
end
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient way though because you're having to go right through all your objects :/.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the records based on a CSV file (you only want to have the records present on the CSV file), you can delete all the records first and then insert the records from the CSV file. You can use [smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) gem which allow background processing.