# Get a random, unvoted-on post in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have a Rails app with three base models: `Entry`, `User` and `Vote`. I need a helper method that will give me a random post for a user to vote on:

```
def next_entry
  Entry.where(:receiving_challenge_id => current_voting_challenge.id).offset(rand(Entry.where(receiving_challenge_id: current_voting_challenge.id).count)).first
end
```

This works, it'll grab a random post every time.

A vote is owned by a user and an entry and they're related through IDs in the database.

**But I don't want to give the user a post they've voted on.**

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Get all the id's of entries

-Get all the id's of entries on which the user voted

-Substract the second one from the first one

-Take any number from that array with the `sample` method and pull the entry with that id from the DB:

```
Entry.find((Entry.all.collect(&:id) - current_user.votes.collect(&:entry_id)).sample)
```

Comment: Isn't sample considered to be extremely bad Rails practice?

Comment: yes, but here you actually are taking a sample from an array of ids and not from an ActiveRecord::Relation object! Either way in your example, you would kinda 'have' to go with the sample method since you don't know all the ids from all the entries, it's not like in some examples where you could select any number below ten and take an id, you HAVE to retrive all of the id's -> have to retrive all of the records.

Answer (score 0):

First, get the entries they have voted on.
Then fetch all different entries

```
voted_entries = user.votes.includes(:entry).collect(&:entry)
unvoted_entries = Entry.where('id NOT IN (?)', voted_entries.collect(&:id))
```

Then you can call `sample` on `unvoted_entries` to get a random one.

Comment: This won't work if the user hasn't voted on any of the entries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/how-to-express-a-not-in-query-with-activerecord-rails  [second answer, comments]

Comment: Didn't know that, that's a shame.