# Rails syntax for where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I write a where clause in Rails to test for multiple values?

This doesn't work:

```
where("wostatus_id = ?", 231 or 230 or 8466 )
```

Also need syntax for something like this:

```
where("wostatus_id != ?", 231 and 230 and 8466 )
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this...

```
where("wostatus_id IN (?)", [231, 230, 8466])
```

or

```
where("wostatus_id NOT IN (?)", [231, 230, 8466])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the normal the [hash condition](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions):

```
Model.where(wostatus_id: [230, 231, 8466])
```

This will produce the expected "IN" query. In Rails 3 there isn't a way to convert this to a "NOT IN" so you will need to fall back on the `where("wostatus_id NOT IN (?)", [230, 231, 8466])` method for that.

In Rails 4, you should be able to do:

```
Model.where.not(wostatus_id: [230, 231, 8466])
```

See also: [How to express a NOT IN query with ActiveRecord/Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/how-to-express-a-not-in-query-with-activerecord-rails)