# HABTM relation find all records, excluding some based on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've looked at some of the similar SO posts relating to this but I'm struggling to get my head around it.

I have a habtm relation between Projects and Users. I'm trying to find all the Projects that a particular user does not belong to but I don't know how.

I've tried this sort of thing:

```
Project.where('project_id != ?', user.id)
```

But it's also obviously wrong.

I'm using rails 3.2.x

Many of the answers relating to this mention scopes but I haven't come across them before (I'm still very new to Rails).

I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/how-to-express-a-not-in-query-with-activerecord-rails) post with one answer suggesting: `Project.where('id not in (?)', user.projects)`

which seems to work, except when `user.projects` is empty. I'm trying `Project.where('id not in (?)', (d.projects.empty? ? '', d.projects))`
 as is suggested in JosephCastro's answer comment thread but it's giving me a syntax error on the second `d.projects`.

**Edit**

Project model snippet that relates to Users

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :before_add => :validates_unique
```

and then

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

Comment: Does using `<>`(SQL) instead of `!=`(Ruby) help at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a scope in your Project model like so:

```
scope :not_belonging_to, lambda {|user| joins(:projects_users).where('projects_users.user_id <> ?', user.id) }}
```

This assumes your join table name matches rails convention for `HABTM` associations

To then get projects that a user doesn't belong to, first find your user, then pass them to the scope like so:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]) # example
@unowned_projects = Project.not_belonging_to(@user)
```

On reflection, that scope won't work as it will find projects that have more than one developer, if one of those is your guy.

Instead, use the following:

```
scope :not_belonging_to, lambda {|user| where('id NOT IN (?)', user.projects.empty? ? '' : user.projects) }
```

Comment: How do I use it then? I'm not familiar with scopes :\

Comment: I'm now getting `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: projects: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" projects_users WHERE (projects_users.user_id <> 1)`. The join table definitely exists though. I feel like this is heading in the right direction now though.

Comment: That SQL doesn't include the join, try changing the table name to a symbol in the joins part (and confirm that table name is right).

Comment: Association named 'projects_users' was not found. Mind if we take this to chat for a few mins?

Comment: Alternatively, try joining directly to the users table, but don't change the where syntax: `scope :not_belonging_to, lambda {|user| joins(:users).where('projects_users.user_id <> ?', user.id) }}` Rails should fill in the joins with the projects_users table. And certainly, chat away!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35203/discussion-between-mike-t-and-matt)

Comment: Really, the most helpful person who's helped me on SO yet

Comment: I had to do `user.projects.map(&:id)` to get the updated answer to work.

Answer (score 1):

From Matt's reply above, which was extremely helpful.

I had trouble with this for a while. I attempted to use the following:

```
scope :not_belonging_to, lambda {|developer| where('id NOT IN (?)', developer.projects.empty? ? '' : developer.projects) }
```

But I received the following error:

SQLite3::SQLException: only a single result allowed for a `SELECT` that is part of an expression:

I found I needed to update the scope,  adding .ids on the end. See below:

```
scope :not_belonging_to, lambda {|developer| where('id NOT IN (?)', developer.projects.empty? ? '' : developer.projects.ids) }
```