# Rails find records where relationship doesn't include an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
class Question
  has_many :participants, :class_name => "User"
end

class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
end
```

Now, given a user, I want to find all questions where this user *has not* participated in.

Something like `Question.where("participants DOES NOT INCLUDE user.id")`, but actually valid. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your relation seems like it should be either a `has_and_belongs_to_many` or a `has_many through` relation. As you've written it, User should have a `belongs_to :question` association on it, which doesn't make sense -- each user would have participated in one and only one question. Can you post the relevant portion of your User model?

Comment: @RobertNubel updated

Answer (score 0):

```
Question.joins(:participants).where("users.id != ?", user.id)
```

Comment: Should users.id be participants.id? Why or why not?

Comment: This will not work correctly. Suppose Question 1 has two participants, A and B; if the given user is A, Question 1 will still be returned because it has a participant (B) who is not A.

Comment: @RobertNubel what about `Question.where.not("participants.id == ?", @user.id)`

Comment: Where clauses only look at one row of the joined relation at a time. You need a GROUP BY, a subquery, or a window function to consider the context of the other rows at the same time. See my answer for my go-to solution for this problem.

Comment: I thought this was a has_many, belongs_to, not a habtm, follow @RobertNubel's answer if you have habtm with join table, the original question didnt specify the User model

Comment: Warning to readers: technically, you should use the `<>` operator with confirming SQL, because the `!=` operator is a vendor extension (that just happens to be supported by some, but not all, SQL products).  If you're going to be writing hardcoded SQL, stick to the standard until you absolutely *need* to deviate, and you'll end up with fewer unpleasant surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet -- in terms of readability and composability -- is a subquery:

```
Question.where(
  "NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM questions_users WHERE question_id=questions.id
   AND user_id=?)", user.id)
```

Comment: Does this assume a new table `questions_users`?

Comment: Users has_and_belongs_to_many questions.. it says the questions_users table exists

Comment: Your has_and_belongs_to_many relation should've automatically created that join table. Otherwise, each user could only have one question.

Comment: Question.joins("LEFT JOIN users ON users.question_id = questions.id").where("users.id IS NULL")    if Your relationships is has_many and not HABTM

Comment: Yeah you will need that join table and change your Question model to has_and_belongs_to_many :users. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18165354/5086701 for setting a scope to check if user belongs to question

Comment: So should this query work if all I've done so far is create 1 instance of a Question model and nothing else? Will it automatically return that question for any user.id? Because right now it's not returning anything. But all I've done is create a single Question and nothing else.

Comment: @moby: yes, it should return all questions if there are no users at all. Are you running exactly what I posted in my answer? Any `joins` on the query would cause the behavior you're seeing, so make sure it's just `Question.where`.