# Has many though with not clause in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have `Post` object that has many `categories` through `post_category`.

How can I find all posts that are not included in a specific category?--scoped to a user So...

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@posts = current_user.posts.where # post is not included @category
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
user.posts.joins(:post_categories).where.not(post_categories: { category_id: @category })
```

Note I'm not looking for posts that do not have a categories. I'm looking for posts that do not have a **specific category**, which may include posts that do not have a category.

I think the problem is the join... joining means by definition I will not include any posts that have no categories, right?

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/how-to-express-a-not-in-query-with-activerecord-rails.

Answer (score 0):

Joins can vary in Rails, but the default (I believe) is to use `INNER JOIN`, which does require presence in both tables - if you're looking for posts without any categories, you'll need a different strategy.

The most "railsy" way I can think of to do this would be in two steps: get the ID's of the Posts you don't want, then get the Posts you do:

```
excepted_ids = PostCategory.where(category_id: @category.id).select(:post_id).distinct
@posts = Post.where.not(id: excepted_ids)
```

I haven't tested this though, so it may not work quite as I expect it to.