# Dismiss records which are included in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I dismiss the returned records which are `LIKE` those from an array.

At the moment I can filter my records only by a string, but I would like to pass an array of strings. Is it possible? And how?

```
array = ['test', 'test1', 'test2']
```

I would like something similar with the below query because `name` can contain a string with multiple words.

```
Model.where.not('name like ?', "%caps%")
```

Comment: which db you are using ?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: Ok i think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/how-to-express-a-not-in-query-with-activerecord-rails

Comment: @Alex Any of the answers did worked for you?

Comment: no, because `name` contains strings with multiple words, and that's why I needed to use `LIKE`, and I still didn't sort this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 4,you can do like this:

```
Model.where.not(name: ['test','test1','test2'])
```

If you want use with `like` then you have do like this

```
@model = Model.where('name like ?', "%caps%") #Retrieving all records like `caps`

@model1 = Model.where('name not in (?)', @model) #Excluding the records in `@model` and gives you the remaining
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
   array = ['test', 'test1', 'test2']
   Model.where('name not in (?)', array)
```

Comment: It does not work, that is why I need to use `LIKE`, because in my column a strings with multiple words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Model.where('name not like (?)', "%caps%")
```