# active record query with `where` and `not in`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to retrieve all Users with two conditions. Their profile_type must be a "Patient" and not in the `blacklisted_ids`

```
blacklisted_ids = [1, 2, 3]

User.where(profile_type: "Patient", id: not_in blacklisted_ids)
```

The following works but I'd like for it to be one query and not a chain. There are many examples of just `where` and just `where.not` but none in a single query.

```
User.where(profile_type: 'Patient').where.not(id: blacklisted_ids)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to express a NOT IN query with ActiveRecord/Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/how-to-express-a-not-in-query-with-activerecord-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chained criteria are (in this case) one query. It translates to one sql statement. If what you want is to syntactically express it in one wrapped where clause then the best you could do is

```
User.where("profile_type = 'Patient' and id not in (?)", blacklisted_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.where('profile_type = ? AND id not in (?)', 'Patient', blacklisted_ids)
```