# How to get ids which doesn't exists in table? (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of ids

`given_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

I want to get all the ids from given_ids which don't exist in Table.

I can do:

`present_ids = Model.where(id: given_ids).pluck('id')
 req_ids = given_ids - present_ids`

But this will be very heavy on the server if `given_ids` size increases.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to express a NOT IN query with ActiveRecord/Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307411/how-to-express-a-not-in-query-with-activerecord-rails)

Comment: Not a bit same. Didn't you understand the question? The answer suggested from the post gives all the other records which are not in `given_ids`. But I need only the ids which are not present in `given_ids`.

Comment: Also could you please remove the mark which is being shown to me above my question for possible duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

I actually think the solution you put into your question is the best.

```
required_ids = given_ids - Model.where(id: given_ids).pluck(:id)
```

It's a single, simple, query, it only returns the id column so the db traffic is minimal, and then you do the array arithmetic.

You are trying to find records that don't exist (as opposed to records not in the given set of arrays) so I can't see a query that could return non-existent records. :)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can search where id is not given in an array.

```
given_ids = [12,3,4,5,6]

1) req_ids = MODEL.find_by_sql("SELECT id FROM MODEL where id != all(array #{given_ids})").map{|row| row.id}

2) req_ids = MODEL.where.not(id: given_ids).pluck(:id)
```

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to use raw sql as something like this:

```
Model.find_by_sql(["SELECT a.id FROM (SELECT unnest(?, ',') as id) a WHERE a.id not in (SELECT t.id FROM model_table t WHERE t.id in (?))", given_ids.join(','), given_ids.join(',')])
```

Maybe join method not necessary.

Comment: when downvoting, please leave comments

Comment: This solution works fine. But I don't know this questioner have a ability to understand this.